# Difference between deploying a JAR on Tomcat server or executing java -jar

Tags: java, tomcat

I got a `POM`-file that generates a `JAR`-file for me. I wanted to test the application and so I ran `java -jar file`, which seems to be starting a tomcat-server in background. Now I tried to simply move the `jar`-file into my `tomcat/webapps`-dir. On accessing `http://localhost:8080` I just get the default tomcat starting page. Is there a difference between moving the `JAR`-file into that directory and starting `tomcat` manually versus using `java -jar file`?

**Edit:** 
Some clarification: I am using a Spring-Boot Application with Angular.

My `POM.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>name</name>
    <description>description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy) article will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But no the `java -jar` command does not start any embedded Application Server by default. The command just starts a JVM process which executes the jar's main class. The reason that java -jar is starting an Application Server in your case, is that you have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web` which contains an embedded tomcat server. This is the default behavior of Spring Boot (you can also use your own AS by excluding the embedded AS).

Answer (score 0):

This is very little information. However judging by the fact that simply running the jar via java -jar seems to work, your application most definitely already brings with it some sort of embedded application server like a Tomcat.

Also you won't be able to simply deploy a jar file on a Tomcat like that. You have to package your application as a [WAR-File](https://www.javatpoint.com/war-file) first to deploy it. When building your WAR, make sure your application does not deliver its embedded application server as it will probably interfere with the Tomcat you are trying to deploy to.

Comment: That's right, I provided my POM-xml. The information I was missing is, that I could not deploy a JAR-file but only a WAR-file. That also means, that using java -jar creates a WAR-file and deploys it into an embedded tomcat?